# Android ANR stacktrace parameters meaning

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

Analyzing ANR stacktrace I am seeing **utm** and **stm** keys.
Can not find information even on developers.android.com to understand meaning of those.
Does anyone has knowledge related to these keys?

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
 | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x752de000 self=0x7faed07bba00
 | sysTid=4843 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faed43d9200
 | state=S schedstat=( 8592162249 8735210421 54080 ) utm=565 stm=293 core=1 HZ=100
 | stack=0x7ffd3a648000-0x7ffd3a64a000 stackSize=8MB
 | held mutexes=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer to my own question.
All credits goes to:

http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-read-dalvik-sigquit-output.html